Repairing base for exterior slider
Any suggestions on how to repair this? Someone my daughter hired installed a glass slider straight on to this concrete. It was obvious the installation was subpar so we removed it and found just concrete below.
My thought was to repair the concrete then place a 1x4 across as a base for the slider. Is that a bad idea? I'm not a contractor just a DIYer trying to help my kid.


Ok so hopefully I got this right. We ended up mixing some concrete and filling the gaps. Then I placed a pressure treated 2x4 as a sill plate. I had to reframe the doorway, which took some work, but eventually got the dimensions needed for this door. Installed the flashing tape and caulked and it seems good now.



Plates aren't usually installed under doors. It needlessly raises sill height and creates a siding void underneath. However, if this suits your purposes, it's probably fine. I'm not familiar with what code allows as a stepover height.
